# Jssor Slider(Banner Slider): How to show a text in two lines

Tags: slider

I'm needing to show the `Text Slide Banner Jsson` on *Two lines*. When I insert text larger than the box size it does not show, I would text aparececi the row below, ie show the text on two lines.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/robisonweb/15388049446/

I managed to position the text box, failed to show the text on two lines.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/robisonweb/15410760422/

I appreciate the help.

[  ]'s Robison

Answer (score 0):

Please change line-height from 45px to 22px, and change font-size from 20px to 16px;
That's to say, replace

```
<thumbnailtemplate style="font-family: verdana; font-weight: normal; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; color:#fff; line-height: 45px; font-size:20px; padding-left:10px;"></thumbnailtemplate>
```

with

```
<thumbnailtemplate style="font-family: verdana; font-weight: normal; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; color:#fff; line-height: 22px; font-size:16px; padding-left:10px;"></thumbnailtemplate>
```

and then you can define 2 line text thumbnail as below,

```
<div u="thumb">Do you notice it is draggable by mouse/finger?<br />Second line</div>
```